How to store multiple choice questions in MongoDB
I have several hundred multiple-choice questions and answers covering a wide range of technologies and competencies. And the number might reach thousands. The concept is that when a user selects a certain technology or ability, questions relevant to that skill should be displayed on the screen along with the user's selections. Which is a better way to store the data, in MongoDB or an RDBMS?
If it is MongoDB how to store and retrieve the data based on a specific skill?

You can easily store that data with either MongoDB or a RDBMS. With Mongo you can use mongoose ODM to help structure the data.
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const QuestionSchema = new Schema({
    question: {type: String, required: true},
    answer: {type: String, required: true},
    optionA: {type: String, required: true},
    optionB: {type: String, required: true},
    skill: {type: String, required: true},
});

Something like the above to start with. You could also link the fields to specific ObjectIDs instead of using Strings if you wanted to do it that way.
